# Google Sheets - Convert year, month, date in separate cells into a "date" in a new cell

Tags: date, google-sheets

Cell A1 has the text (or number, rather) - 2024

Cell A2 has the text (again, or number) - 03

Cell A3 has the text/number - 27

I want cell A4 to now have 2024-03-27 as a date

Is there a way I can get this done?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`DATE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3092969?hl=en) function:

```cpp
=DATE(A1,A2,A3)
```